# Extract seasons and years from a string column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just wondering if there is any other way I can extract the year from a column and assign two new columns to it where one column is for season and one for year?

I tried this method and it seems to work, but only work for year and selected rows:

```
year = df['premiered'].str.findall('(\d{4})').str.get(0)
df1 = df.assign(year = year.values)
```

Output:

```
|premiered||year|
|----------||---|
|Spring 1998||1998|
|Spring 2001||2001|
|Fall 2016||NaN|
|Fall 2016||NaN|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with the `expand` option:

> `expand`: Expand the split strings into separate columns.

```
df[['season', 'year']] = df['premiered'].str.split(expand=True)

#      premiered  season  year
# 0  Spring 1998  Spring  1998
# 1  Spring 2001  Spring  2001
# 2    Fall 2016    Fall  2016
# 3    Fall 2016    Fall  2016
```

Or use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a regex:

- `(\w+)` -- capture 1+ word characters
- `\s*` -- 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` -- capture 1+ digits

```
df[['season', 'year']] = df['premiered'].str.extract('(\w+)\s*(\d+)')

#      premiered  season  year
# 0  Spring 1998  Spring  1998
# 1  Spring 2001  Spring  2001
# 2    Fall 2016    Fall  2016
# 3    Fall 2016    Fall  2016
```

---

Also it would be a good idea to convert the new `year` column to numeric:

```
df['year'] = df['year'].astype(int)
```

Comment: You can also use named capturing groups in `extractall` for an independent DataFrame ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

You could use a split function

```
data = { 'premiered' : ['Spring 1998', 'Spring 2001', 'Fall 2016', 'Fall 2016']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['year'] = df['premiered'].apply(lambda x : x.split(' ')[1])
df
```